# Refactoring tools for Blender?

Tags: workflow

**Are there any refactoring tools for Blender that are currently alive and work with the latest Blender releases?**

By refactoring I mean making changes to data, such as objects and groups, where links to that data in external '.blend' files are updated. For example:

- Renaming data.
- Moving data to different files, which is the same as making a linked copy of that data in an external '.blend' file the source.
- Safe delete, where data is only deleted if it is not linked in external '.blend' files.

I have heard of [Blender-Aid](https://code.google.com/archive/p/blender-aid/), but it seems that project is no longer maintained.

[Blender Asset Manager](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/pipeline/bam.html) is great, but can only be used to rename or move entire '.blend' files rather than their data.

I'm not sure [Asset Manager](https://blendermarket.com/products/asset-management?ref=2) has the refactoring features I am looking for.

I have written [some scripts](https://github.com/KalciferKandari/blender_remap) using Blender's Python API, but because they need to open each '.blend' file to search it, they are extremely slow and cannot be used in practice.

I am currently attempting to use [blendfile.py](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BAM/browse/master/bam/blend/blendfile.py) to rewrite those scripts, but it is turning out to be extremely time-consuming to learn how to use it given the lack of documentation, not just on blendfile.py itself, but also the way '.blend' files are structured.

I truly don't know how anyone can use Blender without refactoring, it's essential for the workflow of any large project. Surely there are already tools out there that do it.